# Multiple cells with multiple textfields to core data attributes

Tags: core-data, uitableview

I have a tableview with 9 cells and in each cell i have at least 2 textfields. Each cell has a label, and the textfields.placeholder are the same in each cell:(example foto below)

[image]

I already created the entities in core data (which are the labels) and the attributes for each one ( which are the textfields.placeholder):

[image]

My question is, how can i set the textfield.text to each attribute in each entity? how to distinguish the textfields?....i don´t think that the IF statment is the best approach ( it would be a LOT!!), and the other problem is the cells are dynamic ( so the user can add more kind of trousers for example)...

Any ideas would be most appreciate... i´m really stuck!.

Thanks in advance.

I´ve been reading a little, but i´m having trouble understanding something: When you say "you can set an object for each cell" are your referring to the classes that core data automatically creates for each entity(when you hit subclass NSmanageobject button),and then i should bind the texfields from each cell to an object of each entity class??.I already have the classes that are referring to each cell, and then i think i should be doing this: Trousers *trouse = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Trousers" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext]; trouse.nameProduct =Textfield.text.and this is the part i don´t no the best approach, because i have more than one textfield in each cell(and i din´t make them property´s of my view) and doing like this, it will be an enourmous amount of work! Can you help me understand better?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CoreData with a table view you should be hooking up model objects to the UI using [NSFetchedResultsController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Have a look at the documentation and examples for this. It's designed to make this sort of thing less painful.

Comment: Thanks for you answer Abizern...my problem is, i have to distinguish the textfields and also the indexpath.section....for example: "product name" in trousers cell...goes to entity trousers, and the textfield.text (product name) goes to the respective attribute in that entity...and so on with the other cells to respective entities...and if i use "if" statement, it will be a LOT of ifs...

Comment: With NSFetchedResultsController you can set an object for each cell and only within that cell does it have to set values for each display. You don't have to do it for the whole table in one place. Have you even looked at?